# If $E$ and $F$ are perpendicular projections, and if $\Vert E-F \Vert < 1$, then the ranges of $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Exercise 6 after $\S$ 87. Norm from Paul R. Halmos's "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" (second edition) invites a comment on the following assertion.

> If $E$ and $F$ are perpendicular projections (linear operators), with ranges $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak N$ respectively, and if $\Vert E-F \Vert < 1$, then dim $\mathfrak M$ = dim $\mathfrak N$.

For reference, $\S \ 87.$ Norm (from the book) has the following definition for the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ of a linear operator:

> $\Vert A \Vert = \inf \ \big\{K: \Vert Ax \Vert \leq K \Vert x \Vert \text{ for all vectors } x\big\}.$

The inner product space, say $\mathcal V$, of the assertion is not specified to be over the complex (or real) field, and is not said to be finite-dimensional or complete either.

I am able to see why the assertion holds in the most trivial cases, say when $E = F$ or when dim $\mathcal V \leq 1$. I am unable to imagine what happens in the general case however, and would appreciate a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about $\mathcal{V}$ not necessarily being finite-dimensional? Do other exercises also omit this detail? If you're in section 87 of something titled "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces", I would guess that by then some blanket assumption would be made earlier in the text that vector spaces are finite-dimensional unless stated otherwise, or something like that. It's uncommon to consider projections in incomplete inner product spaces. Do we at least know that $\mathfrak{M}$ and $\mathfrak{N}$ are finite-dimensional? Or does Halmos define dimension for infinite-dimensional spaces too?

Comment: @Theo Bendit In the preface, Halmos says that he "originally intended this book to contain a theorem if and only if an infinite-dimensional generalization of it already exists". Halmos adds further that his initial intentions "are most clearly seen in the emphasis, throughout, on generalizable methods instead of sharpest possible results".

Comment: @Theo Bendit In the preface, Halmos also invites the reader "to discover if the assertion (in an exercise) is true or false", and "to discuss such alterations of hypothesis and conclusion as will make the true ones false and the false ones true". In accordance with this theme (as I understand), the exercises specify the underlying field and the dimension of the vector space on many occasions throughout the book, though not always. All these observations make me think that Halmos is inviting the reader to discuss the infinite-dimensional case of $\mathcal V$ for the above-mentioned assertion.

Comment: @Theo Bendit In $\S$ 8. Dimension (from this book), Halmos says that "dimension" is defined only for a finite-dimensional vector space. So, we can safely assume that $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak M$ are meant to be finite-dimensional. However, I continue to hold that $\mathcal V$ is not necessarily finite-dimensional. Accordingly, I would appreciate a response on either case (finite-dimensional $\mathcal V$ or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that $\mathfrak{M} \cap \ker F = \{0\}$, otherwise the subspace has at least $1$ dimension, and so we could choose a vector $x$ from it with norm $1$. Then,
$$1 > \|E - F\| \ge \|E(x) - F(x)\| = \|x - 0\| = 1,$$
a contradiction. Similarly, $\mathfrak{N} \cap \ker E = \{0\}$.

This implies that $F|_\mathfrak{M}$ is injective, and so $F$ maps linearly independent subsets of $\mathfrak{M}$ to linearly independent subsets of $\mathfrak{N}$. As such, the image of a basis of $\mathfrak{M}$ under $F$ is linearly independent in $\mathfrak{N}$, proving that $\dim \mathfrak{M} \le \dim \mathfrak{N}$. The reverse inequality holds too, so the dimensions are equal.

Note: I never used the orthogonality of the projections, nor did I use any inner product structure. I just used the fact that $E(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathfrak{M}$, and the corresponding fact about $F$ and $\mathfrak{N}$, which holds for projections.

Comment: Nice. Is your conclusion "$F|_\mathfrak{M}$ is injective" based on the (implicit case) assumption that $\mathcal V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @RajPanse Nope. It's a straightforward consequence of linearity, independent of all dimension concerns. Note that $\ker(F|_\mathfrak{M}) = \mathfrak{M} \cap \ker F$ just by a set-theory argument, and these sets being $\{0\}$ means that, given $x, y \in \mathfrak{M}$ with $F(x) = F(y)$, we get $F(x - y) = F(x) - F(y) = 0$, so $x - y \in \ker(F|_\mathfrak{M}) = \{0\}$, i.e. $x - y = 0$.